# API key must be passed as the API-Key header in every request

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, http, api-key

I want to pass API-Key in the header in every request.

```
 NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSLog(@"%@",request );
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];

[request addValue:@"4eaa90d7175e98732543994eaa90d717" forHTTPHeaderField:@"API-Key"] ;

request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:
           NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:100];

NSLog(@"%@",url);
NSLog(@"%@",[request allHTTPHeaderFields]);
```

The allHTTPHeaderFields is null. am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first initialize request with a `NSMutableURLRequest` which has the header field and then you overwrite it with an `NSURLRequest` that doesn't have the API key in the header field.
Just get rid of this line:

```
request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:
           NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:100];
```